# why function not executes in C# button function but function code run Solved

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a button control in ASP.NET and `Button_Click` function corresponding to it.
 
I have a method `bindEmployeeDetailsToRepeater` that retrieves data from SQL table.

1. When the `bindEmployeeDetailsToRepeater` code is in the `Button_Click` it shows me info in my repeater but
2. When I call `bindEmployeeDetailsToRepeater` from `Button_Click` repeater shows nothing.
3. When I call function from Page_Load then it runs correctly.

Can anyone explain why calling the function from Button_Click (as in code sample below) doesn't work?

```
void bindEmployeeDetailsToRepeater()
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EConnectionString"].ConnectionString);    
                string cmdText = "SELECT * FROM employees where id='testo'";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, con);
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
                Repeater1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Repeater1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }      

protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            bindEmployeeDetailsToRepeater();       
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure your button click event is getting fired. Put a breakpoint in the event and see the behavior

Comment: post your design page and full code behind

Comment: Taleeb, i check my code. All works. When I press on asp.net control it creates method Button1_Click1 but I rename it to Button_Click. This is my mistake. I do not know why it adds number1. And thank you. I need learn more.